# mongodb primary instance stuck in rollback state

Tags: mongodb, recovery

My mongodb cluster has one each Primary, Secondary and Arbiter.

I had to shutdown the Primary instance and bring it up after a while. The secondary instance took over while Primary was down. But when I started the primary back it went to rollback state.

I believed that it will go ROLLBACK -> RECOVERING -> SECONDARY, but it is stuck in a loop ROLLBACK -> RECOVERING -> SECONDARY -> ROLLBACK and every time gives exactly same error "[rsBackgroundSync] rollback couldn't re-get ns:db_name.collection_name _id:_id: "XXXXXX-haeh-4d20-af32-1a82daa62432" 506004/28483088.

I know that last resort will be to re-sync the instance, Is there any other way to recover manually from this loop.

Comment: You might be better off asking on dba, the only way I can think of is to delete the offending rows from the binlog

Comment: After 3 days running in this loop, it auto-recovered. not sure though what happened there